# Scale images in CSS

Tags: css, mobile

I am new to CSS and was wondering how to scale a background image for the header of an iPhone WebApp.

```
    div#header {
        background: rgb(2,100,161) url(../images/header-logo.jpg) repeat-x top; 
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(205,213,223);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(46,55,68);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
        min-height: 85px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
```

Comment: You should mention what is not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good resource for you:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

CSS3 has the background-size property.

You can use that to scale your image to the size you desire. :-)